# bootstrap typeahead not populating with response from promise

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, promise, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

My bootstrap typeahead is as following:

```
<input id="inputId" type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="name for name in getSuggestions($viewValue) " typeahead-on-select="typeaheadOnSelect($item)" ng-trim="false">
```

The getSuggestions() return a promise,like following:

```
$scope.getSuggestions = viewValue => {

    let deferred = $q.defer();

    getSuggestions(viewValue).then(words => {
        deferred.resolve(words); // array of strings
    })
    .catch(()=>{
        deferred.reject([]);
    });

    return deferred.promise;

};
```

**NOTE**: the typeahead works fine when getSuggestions() returns an array without using any promise.

Comment: `$scope.getSuggestions` returns a Promise, right ... so, it's not going to return an Array you can work with

Comment: @JaromandaX the typeahead works fine with promises.I can say so because the typeahead pop up is appearing sometimes,though rarely.

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS the results of resolve() are propagated asynchronously, inside a $digest cycle, not immediately. This means that callbacks registered with then() will only be called (later) when a digest cycle occurs.

So,calling **$digest()** or if needed, $apply() is one way to cause a digest cycle to run.

So the given code needs to be updated to the following:

```
$scope.getSuggestions = viewValue => {

    let deferred = $q.defer();

    getSuggestions(viewValue).then(words => {
        deferred.resolve(words); 
        $scope.$digest();//this triggers the digest cycle 
    })
    .catch(()=>{
        deferred.reject([]);
    });

    return deferred.promise;

};
```